# Include content post Wordpress - Email notification

Tags: wp-mail

I have this mail notification for new post.

All the new post contain arround 100 words and no pictures, so I would like to include in the notification the post content and if is possible, the number of words in the post.

Anybody could help me?

Thanks for all

```
    /* avisar al admin*/
function submit_send_email ($post) {

        $user_info = get_userdata ($post->post_author);
        $strTo = array ('mail@mail.com');
        $strSubject = 'Your website name: ' . $user_info->user_nicename . ' submitted a post';
        $strMessage = 'A post "' . $post->post_title . '" by ' . $user_info->user_nicename . ' was submitted for review at ' . wp_get_shortlink ($post->ID) . '&preview=true. Please proof.';
        wp_mail( $strTo, $strSubject, $strMessage );

}
add_action('future_to_pending', 'submit_send_email');
add_action('new_to_pending', 'submit_send_email');
add_action('draft_to_pending', 'submit_send_email');
add_action('auto-draft_to_pending', 'submit_send_email');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function word_count() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    return $word_count;
}
```

then call it to display the word count:

```
echo word_count();
```

Comment: Sorry, but this function won't work. You use `$post->ID` in your function, but it is not defined in that scope, so it will generate errors.

Answer (score 0):

I find better solution

```
function bavotasan_word_count() {
   return sprintf(
      __( '%s words', 'text-domain' ),
      str_word_count( strip_tags( get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() ) ) )
   );
}
```

to learn more how to use it [function bavotasan_word_count()](http://I%20find%20better%20solution%20%20function%20bavotasan_word_count()%20%7B%20%20%20%20return%20sprintf(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__(%20'%25s%20words',%20'text-domain'%20),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20str_word_count(%20strip_tags(%20get_post_field(%20'post_content',%20get_the_ID()%20)%20)%20)%20%20%20%20);%20%7D%20to%20learn%20more%20how%20to%20use%20it%20[https://bavotasan.com/2015/add-word-count-to-single-posts-in-wordpress/])